# Docker Compose service is inaccessible from localhost

Tags: docker-compose

I am running the following code in docker compose:

```
services:
  vault:
    image: hashicorp/vault:1.15.1
    container_name: vault
    ports:
      - "8200:8200"
    restart: always
    cap_add:
      - IPC_LOCK
    environment:
      - VAULT_DEV_ROOT_TOKEN_ID=myroot
    entrypoint: vault server -dev
```

It creates a `compose_default` network and a container `vault`. Even though I use port mapping `8200:8200`, the container is completely inaccessible from localhost. In total, I cannot access it on `0.0.0.0:8200`, `127.0.0.1:8200`, `localhost:8200` or `http://[::1]:8200`. I tried on the Docker IP - not working as well.

However, if I try to bring up just a Docker container `docker run --name vault --cap-add=IPC_LOCK -p 8200:8200 -e 'VAULT_DEV_ROOT_TOKEN_ID=myroot' hashicorp/vault:1.15.1`, then it works.

I wonder if it has to do something with the network that Docker Compose creates.

I tried many options to bridge the host and Docker networks, none of which work:

```
extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

```
network_mode: host
```

```
network_mode: bridge
```

Can someone share how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that using `entrypoint` was being the problem here and I have to use `command` instead like this:

reference: https://github.com/hashicorp/docker-vault/issues/109#issuecomment-484066180

```
name: vault
services:
  vault:
    image: hashicorp/vault:1.15.1
    container_name: vault
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:8200:8200"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./config/vault.hcl:/vault/config/vault.hcl
    cap_add:
      - IPC_LOCK
    environment:
      - VAULT_DEV_ROOT_TOKEN_ID=myroot
    command: 
      - server
      - -dev
      - -config=/vault/config/vault.hcl
```